# Как загружать изображения в формате, поддерживаемом браузером

Tags: css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка, background-image

Столкнулся с проблемой: Google PageSpeed при тестировании сайта предлагает использовать более современные и удобные расширения картинок для фона. Например webp и jpeg2000. Проблема в том, что первое расширение поддерживается везде, кроме Safari, второе же - наборот, нигде, кроме Safari.
Вопрос: существуют ли какие-то CSS-хаки для определения браузера и подгружения определенной фоновой картинки?
Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - рекомендую использовать [gtmetrix.com](https://gtmetrix.com) (там есть pagespeed от Google) .
2 - рекомендую для "ускорения загрузки сайта" использовать подгрузку изображения - [смотри статью тут](https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/how-to-optimize-image-loading-on-your-website-855020fb41ae) .
Идея такова: ты сжимаешь изображения до миниума, ставишь его в `<img>`-тэг или `background-image:`, а в этот момент с помощью JS подгружаешь изображение в лучшем качестве и после финиша загрузки - меняешь плохую картинку на нормальную

Comment: эээ... а progressive уже не канает?